# Xgboost AFT model predicts infinity

Tags: survival, accelerated-failure-time

I used Xgboost AFT model to predict survival time but get some infinity predictions. Is it normal? How should I interpret that?
I changed aft_loss_distribution from 'normal' to 'logistic', then had inf predictions

Comment: Greetings! It would be a lot more helpful if you could provide much more information about your data, how you fit it, etc. Your question unfortunately doesn't give much for people to work with.

Comment: My data only has right censor or churned cases.                                                    params = {'objective': 'survival:aft',
          'eval_metric': 'aft-nloglik',
          'aft_loss_distribution': 'extreme',
          'aft_loss_distribution_scale': 3,
          'tree_method': 'hist', 
          'learning_rate': 0.5, 
          'max_depth': 10}
bst = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round=10,
                evals=[(dtrain, 'train')])

Comment: [0] train-aft-nloglik:9.79335
[1] train-aft-nloglik:7.75319
[2] train-aft-nloglik:6.59477
[3] train-aft-nloglik:5.95461
[4] train-aft-nloglik:5.61165
[5] train-aft-nloglik:5.43257
[6] train-aft-nloglik:5.34073
[7] train-aft-nloglik:5.29332
[8] train-aft-nloglik:5.26881
[9] train-aft-nloglik:5.25512

Comment: It would be more helpful if you edit that information into your question, but I still think you should contextualize your question more. For example, what does your survival analysis output look like? Do you have other helpful information?